# aws eks access denied aws-auth ConfigMap in your cluster is invalid error on creating eks managed node group using terraform

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, amazon-eks

I have one eks cluster with fargate compute capacity. Now i am adding eks node group as compute capacity. I have created terraform script to create eks node group and launch a template for new node group.

when I am running terraform script using the eks cluster owner role. I am getting the following error message.

```
Error: error waiting for EKS Node Group to create: unexpected state 'CREATE_FAILED', wanted target 'ACTIVE'. last error: 1 error occurred:
            * : AccessDenied: The aws-auth ConfigMap in your cluster is invalid.
```

terraform code

```
#--- setup launch template for eks nodegroups ---#
resource "aws_launch_template" "eks_launch_template" {
    name = "launch-template"
    key_name = var.ssh_key_name
    block_device_mappings {
      device_name = "/dev/xvda"
      ebs {
        volume_size = var.disk_size
      }
    }  
    tag_specifications{
      resource_type= "instance"
      tags = merge(var.tags, { Name = "${local.name_prefix}-eks-node" })
    }
    tag_specifications{
      resource_type= "volume"
      tags = var.tags
    }
    tag_specifications{
      resource_type= "network-interface"
      tags = var.tags
    }
    tag_specifications{
      resource_type= "spot-instances-request"
      tags = var.tags
    }
    vpc_security_group_ids =[aws_security_group.eks_worker_node_sg.id] 
}
#--- setup eks ondemand nodegroup ---#
resource "aws_eks_node_group" "eks_on_demand" {
  cluster_name    = aws_eks_cluster.eks_cluster.name
  node_group_name = "${local.name_prefix}-group"
  node_role_arn   = aws_iam_role.eks_ec2_role.arn
  subnet_ids      = var.private_subnets
  instance_types  = var.nodegroup_instance_types
  launch_template {
    id = aws_launch_template.eks_launch_template.id
    version = aws_launch_template.eks_launch_template.latest_version
  }
  scaling_config {
    desired_size = var.desire_size
    max_size     = var.max_size
    min_size     = var.min_size
  }
  update_config {
    max_unavailable = 1
  }
  tags = var.tags
  lifecycle {
    ignore_changes = [scaling_config[0].desired_size]
  }
}
#--- eks ec2 node iam role ---#
resource "aws_iam_role" "eks_ec2_role" {
  name = "${local.name_prefix}-eks-node-role"
  assume_role_policy = jsonencode({
    Statement = [{
      Action = "sts:AssumeRole"
      Effect = "Allow"
      Principal = {
        Service = "ec2.amazonaws.com"
      }
    }]
    Version = "2012-10-17"
  })
}
#--- attach workernode policy to ec2---#
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "eks_ec2_policy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKSWorkerNodePolicy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.eks_ec2_role.name
}
#--- attach cni policy to ec2---#
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "eks_ec2_CNI_Policy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEKS_CNI_Policy"
  role       = aws_iam_role.eks_ec2_role.name
}
#-- attach ecr read access policy to ec2 ---#
resource "aws_iam_role_policy_attachment" "eks_ec2_ecr_read_policy" {
  policy_arn = "arn:aws:iam::aws:policy/AmazonEC2ContainerRegistryReadOnly"
  role       = aws_iam_role.eks_ec2_role.name
}
```

Comment: Without any code in the question there is really little to know chance to know what is going on.

Comment: @MarkoE i have added code snippet

Comment: I'm guessing you have configured all the networking requirements so this can work? For example, configuring a NAT Gateway for the private subnets etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was in my aws-auth configmap. It looks like aws eks is performing validation on configmap. if your rolemapping contain common username then it eks will throw an error, for example

```
- groups:
  - Dev-viewer
  rolearn: arn:aws:iam::<>:role/<>
  username: {{SessionName}}
- groups:
  - Dev-manager
  rolearn: arn:aws:iam::<>:role/<>
  username: {{SessionName}}
- groups:
  - Dev-admin
  rolearn: arn:aws:iam::<>:role/<>
  username: {{SessionName}}
```

I have change username section of each role.

```
- groups:
  - Dev-viewer
  rolearn: arn:aws:iam::<>:role/<>
  username: view-{{SessionName}}
- groups:
  - Dev-manager
  rolearn: arn:aws:iam::<>:role/<>
  username: manager-{{SessionName}}
- groups:
  - Dev-admin
  rolearn: arn:aws:iam::<>:role/<>
  username: admin-{{SessionName}}
```